# Remove pattern between delimiters if keyword is found

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I have a decently sized document that consists of 5 to 25 rows each, all separated by a bunch of === characters.

What I want to do is keep only some text, which is fine, but I also want to remove everything between these === characters if a certain keyword is found, and I am at a loss.

In this example I'd like to remove everything between the === characters that contains X, including A, B, F and G.

> ======================================================================
>
> A = 1
>
> B = 2
>
> C = 3
>
> D = 4
>
> E = 5
>
> ======================================================================
>
> A = 0
>
> B = 10
>
> F = 5
>
> G = 10
>
> X = 20
>
> ======================================================================

Anyone got an idea?

Expected output:

A = 1

B = 2

C = 3

D = 4

E = 5

Thanks!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @JCJ Edit your question to show formatted output.

Comment: With GNU AWK: `awk '!/X|F|G/' ORS= RS='===+'`?

Comment: @andlrc `ORS=` not needed.

Comment: @123 I havn't tested it, I'm on a phone, but I would assume you would get a ton of leading and trailing newlines if `ORS` is not blank

Comment: You'd get one extra above and below, so you would still have an extra newline using `ORS=`.

Comment: `awk -v RS='={3,}+\n' -v ORS= 'NF && !/(^|\n)(X|F|G) *=/' file` will get it without any extra newlines in output.

Comment: andlrc, your solution worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU AWK: `awk '!/X|F|G/' ORS= RS='===+'` – andlrc